# A pair of ambiguous tags: [nested] and [non-nested]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-reorganization

We have [nested](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nested) with 216 Qs and also [non-nested](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-nested) with 22 Qs. Neither tag has a wiki excerpt. Both are terribly ambiguous.

AFAIK, "nested" can refer (and this tag *is* being used to refer) to various conceptually different things that have little to do with each other:

1. Nested data / nested experimental design (nested factors in ANOVA, nested random effects in mixed models, etc.)
2. Nested models (e.g. doing LR test on two nested models)
3. Nested cross-validation

**Update April 2016:** I looked through the last 50 threads tagged with [nested]. 39 are about nested data (split ~50:50 between ANOVA and mixed models); 1 is about nested models; 10 are about nested cross-validation. Among the [non-nested] threads, most seem to be about nested models.

I suggest to split these two tags into three new tags, corresponding to the above categories.

**Questions:**

1. Would `[nested-data]` be an okay name for nested anova/lmer stuff? We could have nested-anova, nested-random-effect, nested-factor as synonyms. There is also a `[multilevel-analysis]` tag, but people asking about nested anova do not usually use this terminology...
2. `[nested-models]` would do, wouldn't it?
3. Do we need `[nested-cross-validation]` tag, or can we retag these threads to `[cross-validation]` and that's it?

Comment: I upvoted the question. I'm not sure what I think the answer should be. The problem is that "nested" isn't an noun phrase, it's an adjective. So we either end up with as many different `[nested-____]` tags as can exist, or we have a single `[nested]` tag that means something different depending on the other tags applied.

Comment: @gung That's an interesting perspective. Do you know any other adjective-like tags that can be combined with various other tags to refer to different concepts? I am wondering if this is something that can work well, or should rather be avoided.

Comment: I don't know. It really needs some hard thought, but I've never really had a chance to work though it.

Comment: Bumped again ;-).

Comment: @gung After it was bumped *again*, I made an update with some usage statistics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My proposal:

1. Re-tag usage #1 to [nested-data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nested-data):

   > Use this tag for nested random effects in mixed models and nested factors (or nested design) in ANOVA.
2. Re-tag usage #2 to [nested-models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nested-models):

   > One model is "nested" in another if it is a constrained version of it. Nested models can be compared with a likelihood-ratio test. Use this tag for questions about comparing non-nested models too.
3. Remove usage #3. I don't like [nested-cross-validation] tag too much because it would be a proper subset of [cross-validation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cross-validation); also, most existing threads about nested CV are not using [nested] tag anyway.

---

**Update (May 5):** [non-nested] is gone.

**Update (May 8):** I have moved all threads that are *not* about [nested-data] out of [nested]. The remaining 172 questions can now be moved into [nested-data] via mod action.

**Update (May 9):** This is done, see comments. Case closed.

Comment: presently merging [nested] into [nested-data]

Comment: I believe it's complete.

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks! If possible, could you now remove the synonym mapping nested-->nested-data? There is no sense in automatic mapping of nested into either nested-data or nested-models in the future.

Comment: I have some misgivings about that (such as people now using "nested" again), but done as requested.

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks. I would not worry about reappearing of "nested". So far, whenever we replaced tag A by A-foo and A-bar (I think this happened a couple of times), A did not reappear. I think this makes sense because when people start typing A, they get A-foo and A-bar as suggestions and will choose one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You apparently are identifying a very nested topic. I have read about either well-or ill-defined other uses:  [nested-anova](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nested-anova), [nested-ancova](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nested-ancova) (nested analysis of variance or covariance with nested nominal variables), [nested-data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nested-data) (of which hierarchically structured data are a subclass), [nested-sampling](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nested-sampling).

So it definitely makes sense. Could this process lead to the need of a tag ontology?

REM: [What is the difference between a “nested” and a “non-nested” model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4717/what-is-the-difference-between-a-nested-and-a-non-nested-model)

References:

- [Nested Sampling for General Bayesian Computation](http://www.mrao.cam.ac.uk/~steve/maxent2009/images/skilling.pdf), Skilling, 2006

Comment: Hmm, nested-data might actually be a better name for my point #1 (nested-design or nested-effects). Nested-anova is anova with nested factors (isn't it?), so it's the same thing. What is nested-analysis? If you mean analysis of nested data, then it's the same thing too. Can't say anything about "nested sampling" because I don't know what that is...

Comment: I think [nested-data] can cover nested ANOVA, nested ANCOVA, nested factors, nested experimental design, nested random effects in mixed models, and also "nested analysis" (whatever it is). Don't you think?

Comment: @amoeba I think [tag:nested-data] is a bit too data-centric: if you do not like  [tag:nested-models] or [tag:nested-analysis], perhaps [tag:nested-processing]? I do not fear the confusion with parallel processing as we are on SE.stat

Comment: Wait, I do like nested-models, see point #2 in my answer. But when one has nested factors in anova, it is because the dataset is nested itself; it's not a choice that an analyst does, the analysis *has* to incorporate nested factors if they are nested; that's why I like nested-data.

Comment: @amoeba The choice of the grouping, the depth of nesting can be user dependent, isn't? I tend to believe that the act of choosing data, the way they will be processed, is a part of the processing (as it involves interpretation), but one could call that an opinion